# How do you formalize this reasoning?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, formal-proofs, formal-systems

There is this simple number theory problem which says "how many 4 digit numbers that are divisible by 3 and whose digits exclude 2, 4, 6 and 9 exist?"

the solution is quite intuitive:

each digit can be either 0, 1, 3, 5, 7 or 8, except the first digit, which can't be 0.

now, say our number is $n=10x+y$. if $x\equiv0\mod{3}$, then $y$ can be either 0 or 3.
if $x\equiv1\mod{3}$, then $y$ can be either 5 or 8.
if $x\equiv2\mod{3}$, then $y$ can be either 1 or 4.

there are always 2 values $y$ can take, so there are $5\times6\times6\times2=360$ values of $n$.

My question is how can you formalize this solution. More precisely, write a proof with formal sybolism about: $$|\{n\in\mathbb{N}:1000\le n\le 9999\land\exists k\in\mathbb{N}(n=3k)\land\exists a,b,c,d\in\{0,1,3,5,7,8\}(n=1000a+100b+10c+d)\}|=360$$
that uses the aforementioned reasoning.

I've tried several things but still can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Hint;  with those exclusions the digit in the units place can be $0,1,2\pmod 3$ with equal probability. (that is, there are two options which are $0\pmod 3$, two options which are $1\pmod 3$ and two options that are $2\pmod 3$).

Comment: Am I misunderstanding, or is your question just "how do I write this proof up using formal symbolism"? If so, then the formal systems tag would be a better choice. You already have a fully functional proof. If it is just a matter of how to write up in a formal language, then the actual question isn't about number theory.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I will edit the tags. Thanks